# RESTFUL web application with Zend framework and Extjs

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, rest, extjs

I'm trying to create a web application using a JavaScript framework (eg Extjs) for client side and Zend framework for server side.

I have read a lot about REST and I wanna use it in my application. I have created an Extjs form which asynchronously fetches data for country names, auto-completes usernames, etc.

How should I create my Zend framework controller? How many controllers should I create for just a single form? I have a getAction in my controller and the request is like:
       http://localhost/myproject/myform 
so if I wanna process different Get requests (eg, country names, cities, etc.) should I create a switch statement in my getAction for every resource or should I create different controllers for just one form until I don't have to use switch?

```
    class IndexController extends Zend_Rest_Controller {

public function init() {

}

public function indexAction() {

}
public function getAction() {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender ( true );
    //switch statement for diffrent resource requests goes here
}
public function postAction() {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender ( true );
}
public function putAction() {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender ( true );
}
public function deleteAction() {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender ( true );
}

    }
```

What do you suggest? **Should I create many controllers for just one extjs form?**

Comment: public function init() {
   $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender ( true );
}  
And then you remove that line from each method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZF has some components to assist with doing things RESTfully.  In particular, check out Zend_Rest_Controller and Zend_Rest_Route.

You'll want a controller for each type of resource (cities, countries, etc), each controller should extend Zend_Rest_Controller.

Tutorials on getting Zend_Rest_Controller and Zend_Rest_Route are easy to google.

Comment: so there will be lots of controllers.oh yes. There are some tutorials on zftutorials.com and i have been searching for month.